# Adding margins to listview

Tags: android, listview, layout

I am following a tutorial and I did not understand why exactly the margins that I applied to a list view contained within a relative layout does not affect the look when I test it on a device. However, if I put everything in a LinearLayout container it looks as it should. I don't understand why the layout does not work without this LinearLayout.

This is my code in layout for my listView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/inbox_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/inbox_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inbox_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/messageIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/message_list_item_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/message_list_item_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_message_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_picture"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/senderLabel"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/messageIcon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/messageIcon"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=" created at: 03.17.15"
        android:id="@+id/createdAtLabel"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/senderLabel"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/senderLabel"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result of the code:
[image]

this is the code without the LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/inbox_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/inbox_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inbox_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/messageIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/message_list_item_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/message_list_item_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_message_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_picture"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/senderLabel"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/messageIcon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/messageIcon"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=" created at: 03.17.15"
        android:id="@+id/createdAtLabel"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/senderLabel"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/senderLabel"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the result of this layout:

[image]

Comment: nesting relative layout in linear layout is nor required here

Comment: It is r7v, otherwise the margins that I apply to the RelativeLayout does not work at all and there is no the space in-between the list views.

Comment: is this your listview row layout ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "row", but this is my only layout for the list view

Comment: why dont you use dividerheight for spacing between rows and give the padding to the parent layout of your listview , can you post your activity/fragment layout where you have your listview

Comment: That could work as well, but I am trying to understand how this works and what. PS. I have updated the question with more code and a screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80395/discussion-between-georgi-koemdzhiev-and-r7v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin is outside a view , ListView uses AbsListView.LayoutParams by default, which doesn't include any margin support, just the height and width, thats why, it simply ignores the params value for margins. Try using padding for your relative layout instead

Comment: I see know, so putting the relative layout inside another layout as a container allows us to use margins, if I am correct. Thank you fro your answer.